# Laravel Query Builder Raw Expressions

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

How can one write raw expressions in a `join` clause using query builder given this?

```
SELECT 
    rating.post_id,
    sum(rate_like), 
    sum(rate_dislike), 
    (sum(rate_like) + sum(rate_dislike)),
    column_rating
from rating
inner join (
    select 
        post_id, 
        round(round((((sum(rate_like) / (sum(rate_like) + sum(rate_dislike)) * 100) * 0.5) / 10) * 2) / 2, 1) as column_rating
    from rating group by post_id
) as rating_table
on rating.post_id = rating_table.post_id
group by rating.post_id
```

I've tried achieving it the following way, but it doesn't work:

```
DB::table('db_test')->table('rating')
                     ->join('rating_table', 'select ... from rating as rating_table')
                     ->raw('rating.post_id,
                            sum(rate_like), 
                            sum(rate_dislike), 
                            (sum(rate_like) + sum(rate_dislike)),
                            column_rating')
```

Comment: I'm asking out of curiosity - you know what kind of SQL you're after, you know how to deal with Laravel - why don't you simply create a MySQL view, create a model that reads the view and completely give up porting this complex query to Laravel? It's doable, but the thing is - to create the view, you'll spend 5 seconds since all you have to do is add `CREATE VIEW view_name AS...` in front of your `SELECT` and you'll spend 3 lines of code creating an Eloquent model that reads from it. In total, less than 10 seconds of your time.

Comment: BTW: what error do you get? I would have used the approach above as suggested by @N.B. not for simplicity only, but improved experience and performance. Unless you have a specific reason for doing otherwise, that's the best approach I will equally recommend.

Comment: *Should you still consider using a `joint` approach, do update your post with the error you get with your current approach as well as enough information to replicate your scenario for a closer look.*

Comment: `rating_table` is not a real table, so you cannot use it that way, but you can just use `raw` there too. On the other hand: am I missing something or are you joining your table with itself? Your `group by post_id` is the same for your outer query and your subquery, and you are joining on that `post_id` again, so you will get a 1:1 relation of the same table, which just adds another column; so you could just remove the join and use that column directly, which would both solve your laravel problem (because you don't have a subquery anymore that you have to join with) and be faster.

Comment: @Solarflare I was able to successfully query it using `->join(DB()->raw('select...')`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully query it using `->join(DB()->raw('select...')`